# Code for switching keyboard view android studio

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am creating a custom Android keyboard at the moment. I have the letter page completed, but I do not know how to create a button that will switch to the symbols view.
I want to click the 'Sym' button and switch the view to symbols.
What methods should I be using etc?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o01Al.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your "Sym" key with code like

```
<Key android:codes="-2" android:keyLabel="Sym"/>
```

and make action to your keyboard.java using `onKey` method

```
            case Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE:
            keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols);
            kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            break;
```